# how to point url to a different directory

Tags: .htaccess, url, directory, server

please kindly assist, am quite stuck here.
i am working a web app that require users to register and have individual directory on my site.
i want the users directory to be like: 
http://example.com/theusername

this i could make work by creating folders on my site root for each user. but that will keep my root directory over clustered.
is it possible for me to make the user directory to be: http://example.com/u/theusername but have but assess it via http://example.com/theusername ??

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes sure that can be done. You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index|excluded1|excluded2)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!u/).+)$ u/$1 [L,NC]
```

You can include your exclusions in `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}` using regex alternation OR else have more `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}` lines like shown above.

`RewriteRule` in my answer is using a negative lookahead `(?!u/)` which means match only if not followed by `u/`. Action is to always route the `/username` to `/u/username` using `u/$1`.

#### References:

- [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite Technical Details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite In-Depth Details](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but please I don't have vast knowledge on .htaccess syntax. Please kindly explain in detail.

Comment: Have added explanation and reference links in my answer. Let me know if this answer works for you.